# c# How to get standard font style object in Word

Tags: c#, fonts, ms-word, word-style

I'm inserting variable text from a *.html file into a Word document and have to adapt the font(name and size) of the inserted text to the rest of the document.
I have a working solution but I don't like the way I did it, so I'm searching another way to get the standard font name and size from Word application.
Another problem is that NameLocal can be in different languages. So I also need another way to find the Headers. I already tried Style.Type but it has always value "1"
My code so far:

```
foreach (Word.Style style in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Styles)
  {
    if (style.NameLocal.Equals("Normal")) // find correct style object
    {
      float size = style.Font.Size;
      string font = style.Font.Name;

      foreach (Word.Paragraph paragraph in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs)
      {
        if (paragraph.Range.get_Style().NameLocal.Contains("Heading")) // find all headers
        {
          paragraph.Range.Font.Size = size;
          paragraph.Range.Font.Name = font;
        }
      }
      break;
    }
  }
```

The reason why I'm not simply changing the style is so the headers are still marked as headers.
I'm pretty clueless atm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For built-in styles, the Word object model provides the [enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdbuiltinstyle?view=word-pia) `WdBuiltinStyle`. Using this instead of a `string` value (the local name of a style) makes specifying a style language-independent. In addition, the built-in styles will always be present in a document so there's no need to loop the `Styles` collection of a document to get a particular style.

So, for example:

```
Word.Document doc = Globals.ThisAddin.Application.ActiveDocument;
Word.Style style = doc.Styles[Word.WdBuildinStyle.wdStyleNormal];
float size = style.Size;
string font = style.Font.Name;
foreach (Word.Paragraph paragraph in doc)
{
    if (paragraph.Range.get_Style() = Word.WdBuildinStyle.wdStyleHeading1)
    {
     paragraph.Range.Font.Size = size;
     paragraph.Range.Font.Name = font;
     }
}
```

Comment: I already saw the WdBuildinStyles, but couldn't figure out how to use them properly ... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just added a follow up question ... would you mind having a look at it?

Comment: Please create a *new* question @DomMa - you can add a link to this one if you feel it contains important background material. The site concept is Q&A - it's not a typical "discussion forum". So the rule is one question per "Question".  When you post, please also provide the exact text of the error you're getting. Right now, I'm on mobile device, but when I'm at a "real" machine I'll take a look at new questions.

Comment: Done:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53628979/c-sharp-comparing-style-objects-in-ms-word