# c# comparing style objects in MS Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, word-style

I have to edit all headings inside a word document.

I tried this:

```
Word.WdBuiltinStyle[] styleArray = {
    Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1,
    Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading2,
    Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading3,
    Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading4,
    Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading5,
    Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading6,
    Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading7,
    Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading8,
    Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading9
  };

  foreach (Word.Paragraph paragraph in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs)
  {
    if (styleArray.Any(a => a.Equals((Word.WdBuiltinStyle)paragraph.Range.get_Style())))
    {
      paragraph.Range.Font.Size = size;
      paragraph.Range.Font.Name = font;
    }
  }
```

But it says I can't cast and I#m feeling this is not a very good way to do it.

It also doesn't work with

```
if (styleArray.Contains(paragraph.Range.get_Style()))
```

Any help on this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a difference between the built-in style enumeration and an actual style. That's why the comparison isn't working. The array needs to be an array of *styles*. For example:

```
Word.Document doc = Globals.ThisAddin.Application.ActiveDocument;
enter code here
Word.Style[] styleArray = {
  doc.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1),
  doc.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading2),
  doc.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading3) //and so on
};
```

Comment: Great @DomMa :-) Hope things continue to go smoothly!